# How to rename linux directories using javascript function

Tags: javascript, directory, names

Brand new to stackoverflow. I've looked this up and can't seem to find a clear cut answer based on my situation. I have an Ubuntu Server running Apache for a shared file system that I can view on my IP's port 80. I've made a style.css file and am using a php file for the index of Apache. It simply uses a for loop to get all of the current directory's file/directory names, and then puts them into a table with an  that takes me to the directory/file you click on.

So far I've successfully put an "edit" button that makes the name of all files/directories editable, and then saved the new names onto the localStorage. My question is how do I use a FileSystemObject to get the directory of the edited file/directory and change the name to the new content stored in the localStorage? I read that FSO's only work with windows? Is there another API that I can use to grab the directories and change their names?

Thanks

Comment: You tagged this PHP, but you don't want a PHP answer?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do here?  Are you trying to change file/directory names on the server?  If so, create an ajax call to call your PHP server and instruct it to make the name change on the client's behalf.  A browser can't change a file on the server directly.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without ajax? The path for the index.php is different for every directory (each index is in its directory), and the .js that the indexes are referencing is on place. So i assume I'd run into problems when calling: xhr.open( 'post', '/path/to/php', true );